# How to fix autocompletion for some libraries in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, autocomplete, settings, libraries

I have installed some library's in eclipse. It's irritating that autocompletion not works for some libraries. For example, I type: `JButton` the eclipse popup with suggestions will appear when I type the first characters. This is how it should. But when I type `glBegin()` the popup will not be shown, and I have to type all imports manually on top of the file.
I think I have setup the jar files correctly.
Is this a known issue with you? How can I possibly fix it?
I can also not find the javadoc of lwjgl.

Comment: Check your build path and verify whether you added the libraries to build path. Content assist or auto completion will work if classes are found in build path.

Comment: I think it has to do with static imports. When I type GL11.glBegin() (with a normal, non-static import), the popup menu will be displayed.